# cmake: special targets like "all" and "test" having the same name in multiple places in the build tree?

Tags: cmake

cmake does not allow you to create multiple targets having the same name at different places in the build tree using add_custom_target().
However, it does provide special targets with that property notably:

- all
- test
- install

Each of these when run within a sub-tree will apply to just that sub-tree.
Is there a way achieve the same for user targets?

Here is a simplified example:

toplevel *CMakeLists.txt*:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

add_custom_target(thing)

add_subdirectory(sub1)
add_subdirectory(sub2)
```

*sub1/CMakeLists.txt*:

```
add_executable(foo foo.cpp)

add_custom_target(thing.sub1 DEPENDS foo)
add_dependencies(thing thing.sub1)
```

*sub2/CMakeLists.txt*:

```
add_executable(bar bar.cpp)

add_custom_target(thing.sub2 DEPENDS bar)
add_dependencies(thing thing.sub2)
```

I can get almost the behaviour I want in that:

- *make thing* at the top level builds thing.sub1 & thing.sub2
- *make thing.sub1* at the top level or in sub1 builds thing.sub1
- *make thing.sub2* at the top level or in sub2 builds thing.sub2

What I would like is to be able to just run *make thing* and have it apply to the
current sub-directory like the *all* target does.

**Is this possible?
If not is it a missing feature or would it be a misfeature and if so why?**

---

**Solution (almost)**

@zuafi's direction led me to a solution.

**It is currently possible but only using deprecated behaviour** from policy [CMP0002](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/policy/CMP0002.html).
There is effectively a missing feature for adding local targets which is covered by [this open ticket](http://public.kitware.com/Bug/view.php?id=6348).

My workaround is to implement *add_local_target()* for myself is as follows:

```
# determine whether local targets should be legal
if("${CMAKE_GENERATOR}" MATCHES "Make")
  cmake_policy(SET CMP0002 OLD)
  # property seems to be deprecated
  set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY ALLOW_DUPLICATE_CUSTOM_TARGETS 1)
  set(ALLOW_LOCAL_TARGETS 1)
  message("using Makefile generator")
else()
  cmake_policy(SET CMP0002 NEW)
  message("Generator=${CMAKE_GENERATOR}")
endif()

# add a custom target with the same name as another (posssibly global) target iff permitted
# see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35489093/cmake-special-targets-like-all-and-test-having-the-same-name-in-multiple-pl
function(add_local_target target)
  if(ALLOW_LOCAL_TARGETS)   
    set(dependencies "${ARGN}")
    foreach(dependency IN LISTS dependencies)
       if(TARGET ${dependency})
          list(APPEND targets ${dependency})
       else()
          message("${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/CMakeLists.txt: warning: dependency ${dependency} for add_local_target(${target}) is NOT a target")
       endif()
    endforeach()
    add_custom_target(${target} DEPENDS ${targets})
  endif()
endfunction()
```

This combines well with target paths like *target.subdir* which can be used as a fall-back if using a non Makefile generator.
I just use:

```
add_local_target(thing DEPENDS thing.sub1)
```

---

**Update**

I think this solution may be subtly broken. If you attempt to build a 'local' target it *may* build some other 'local' targets as well. However, it will build at minimum what it is supposed to build. It will also build less than a global project wide target with the same name would build. I haven't managed to track this down yet as the makefiles generated by cmake are somewhat gnarly.

Comment: Note: I don't like my solution as it relies on using a policy as a feature toggle which is exactly what they don't want - see https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-policies.7.html#manual:cmake-policies%287%29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible... but not with all generators. Particularly it is Ok w/ *UNIX Makefiles* (see [CMP0002](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/policy/CMP0002.html) description). And as for me I want to have all unit tests in my project tree to have the same name (I have a bash completion for that name :), so I use the following macro helping me to declare executables:

```
macro(set_unit_test_target_name OUTPUT_VARIABLE DEFAULT_VALUE)
    cmake_policy(GET CMP0002 _may_use_same_name)
    if(_may_use_same_name STREQUAL "OLD")
        set(${OUTPUT_VARIABLE} "unit_tests")
    else()
        set(${OUTPUT_VARIABLE} ${DEFAULT_VALUE})
    endif()
endmacro()

# usage example
set_unit_test_target_name(UNIT_TESTS someTestExecutable)
add_executable(${UNIT_TESTS} ... )
```

so for *NIX builds all executables would be named `unit_tests`, and have unique names for other generators…

Comment: Your answer with is almost perfect. I have updated my question to include 
a solution derived from your hint.
I would add my own answer and accept it but you deserve the credit.

Policy CMP0002 mentions a property ALLOW_DUPLICATE_CUSTOM_TARGETS but I can't seem to enable it.
Its probably lost to bitrot from cmake 2.6 or earlier.
[http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/index.php?title=CMake_Policies_Design_Discussion&redirect=no]
suggests the property predates policies though the cmake documentation doesn't mention this.